# JSON.NET serialize and deserialize fragments

Tags: c#, json.net

I have queues of objects that I continuously flush to files for offline processing.  Each object type gets its own file, and I want to use JSON.NET to serialize the objects.

so let's say I have a `Queue<LogInfo>`, and every time I flush it, it will go to the same file. I serialize each object one at a time and append them to a string builder, separated by commas. So my file will look like.

```
{ "Id":1,"Name":"a"},
{ "Id":2,"Name":"b"},
```

Now when I want to process these, I read in the file, but precede all the text by a "[" and at the end I append a "]", so that JSON.NET can deserialize the fragments as a list of LogInfo objects.

I realize this probably isn't the intended use of the JSON serializer, but is there a better way? Is there I way I can read in the fragments (serialized objects) one-by-one without having to hack a `[` and `]` in there?, or a way to tell the serializer I'm giving it a comma-separated series of objects?

Comment: Is a database queue not an option?

Comment: no, it needs to be a file--a database would be too easy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Just put them in a list and serialize that using Json.NET. One object per line isn't a valid JSON document and if it is as you say, you just want a list anyway. So why are you not making it a list?

Comment: because i don't have the full list up front, only parts of it at a time.

Comment: But you can still build a list of the items that needs to get serialized and you shouldn't be afraid of building a new list (a subset even so) it's perfectly valid thing to do. Right now you might be a little more memory conservative but in a managed world short lived allocations are free.

Comment: but then wouldn't I have the same problem? It would deserialize to List<List<T>>, but I'd have to separate each serialized list with a comma and put a [ and ] at the beginning and end of the file, right?

Comment: I don't see why you would have this, you have a queue, which effectively already is a list and simply doing `.ToList()` and serializing should do it. Resulting in a `List<LogInfo>`. But if you're appending to a file on disk, JSON cannot really help with that, it's a document format (it always has a begining and end). You should consider splitting each document into it's own file as well, if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather encourage using a serializer better suited to this, such as [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) created by our very own [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell), in lieu of trying to force JSON.NET into submission. Protobuf will allow you to stream data into a file and stream it back out very easily.

You simply declare that you're expecting a list vs requiring the deserializer to recognize that a list has been provided. As a side benefit, your resultant files will be smaller due to protocol buffers aggressive compaction.

Comment: Protocol buffers are fundamentally different from Json.NET in design and metadata. I would use protocol buffers if had a better understanding of the problem but otherwise no, it's too different to just swap Json.NET for protocol buffers.

Comment: sounds cool but i'd rather not deal with decorating all my classes with serialization attributes